# Graphic scaling of neural network SummaryGraphics

Tags: graphics, image, neural-networks

[image]

Same funky scaling occurs when dragging the `SummaryGraphics` with the mouse; so, the issue is in the graphics itself not in the `Image` function

Comment: version 11.3 on Debian 9